# Add row after three columns

Tags: posts, loop, twitter-bootstrap

on my newssite i have the first post in a full-width column, after that all older post are in three columns per row. But now i want that wordpress put after every three columns a  and  to keeps the elements into rows.
I tried to adjust the following solutions:
[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922657/adding-a-row-div-after-every-four-post-in-wordpress)
[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496052/wrap-every-2-wordpress-posts-inside-bootstrap-row-class)
[Solution 3](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-multiple-loop-how-to-for-3-rows-each-row-3-posts)

But nothing of that will work.

Here is my code to get my posts:

```
       <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
   <div class=" entry-content">
   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <?php $c++;
   if( !$paged && $c == 1) :?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'aktuelles-first' ); ?>

   <div class="accordion">
   <div class="row">

   <?php else :?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'aktuelles' ); ?>


      <?php endif;?>

   <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php endif; ?>

       </div></div>

    </main><!-- #main -->
       </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Is there any solution without changing my way to get the posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea of what I think you could do if I understand the problem correctly:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div class=" entry-content">
        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            $post = $posts[0];
            $c = 0;
            $i = 0;

            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                // start a new row for the first post and every three posts
                if ( ! $paged && ( 0 == $c || 0 == ( $c % 3 ) ) ) {
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'aktuelles-first' );
                    echo my_code_open_row();
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'aktuelles' );
                }

                // close the opened divs above
                if ( $i > 2 ) {
                    echo my_code_close_row();
                    $i = 0; // Reset the row close counter
                }

                $c++;
                $i++;
            }

            // Close the row if we never get to the row closing
            // before we leave the loop
            if ( $i < 2 ) {
                echo my_code_close_row();
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
function my_code_open_row() {
    return <<<HTML
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="row">
HTML;
}

function my_code_close_row() {
    return <<<HTML
        </div>
    </div>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for your help and the explanations into your code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm entirely understanding the question, however it looks like you're using $c to track which post you're on. I think what you're missing is you need to set it up so every 4th post is treated differently, correct? You can test for that using the modulus operator `if ($c % 4 == 0) {` - then add the special HTML for that row. And remember to test again and close the divs as need be.